# NGINX try_files not working: 500 Server Error

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) to get my server to fall back to a different file location, but I can't get it to work. Instead, I get a 500 Server Error. Here is the file structure:

opt > web > archive

First I want to check web, then archive if the file is not in web. Ex: If I want to grab test.mp4, first I want to look in /opt/web/ then /opt/web/archive

Here is the config:

```
http {

  server {
    listen 80;
    root  /opt/web/;

    location / {

      try_files $uri/ /opt/web/archive/;

      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

      # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

      autoindex on;

      set $no_cache "";

      if ($request_uri ~* \.mp4$) {
        set $no_cache "1";
      }

      proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
      proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    }

  }

}
```

Ideas?

```
try_files $uri/ $uri/archive/;
```

also will not work

Comment: `/opt/web/archive/` is not a file. And, you need to look at your error log.

Comment: Well, the user would be looking for a file When the look for test.mp4, I first want to look in /opt/web/ then opt/web/archive/ I thought you could use two directories for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user requests for `http://www.example.com/test.mp4`, the `$uri` variable will contain `/test.mp4`.

Now, when you have `try_files $uri/ /opt/web/archive/;` in your configuration, nginx will try these files:

```
/opt/web/test.mp4/
/opt/web/archive/
```

So, you should use:

```
try_files $uri archive$uri;
```

in your configuration.

Another smaller issue is your use of `if`. Instead of this:

```
set $no_cache "";

if ($request_uri ~* \.mp4$) {
    set $no_cache "1";
}

proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
```

I recommend that you use this:

```
location ~ \.mp4$ {
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There were two issues with this, first, the try_files was incorrect, causing the redirect to loop endlessly until it error:

> *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/06000513//archive//archive//archive//archive//archive//archive//archive//archive//archive//archive//archive/", client: 00.000.000.00, server: , request: "GET /06000513/ HTTP/1.1", host: "myhost.com"

The resolution was to use `try_files $uri /archive$uri =404;` over `try_files $uri/ /opt/web/archive/;`

The second issue was caching, because we turned off caching, there were errors when looking for the file in seperate locations. The easiest fix was just to remove that:

```
  set $no_cache "";

  if ($request_uri ~* \.mp4$) {
    set $no_cache "1";
  }

  proxy_no_cache $no_cache;
  proxy_cache_bypass $no_cache;
```

New config:

```
http {

  server {
    listen 80;
    root  /opt/web/;

    location / {

      try_files $uri /archive$uri =404;

      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

      # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

      autoindex on;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip with `=404`. This solved my problem when expecting HTTP 404 responses for non-existing files. Instead the server returned a 500 response, which was quite unexpected.